# What issue is this Mary Jane monologue from?

Tags: spider-man, episode-identification, marvel

I've been looking for the quintessential Mary Jane monologue from Spider-Man (if there is one), for a friend's script.  Something well-written, evocative of MJ's character, and longer than "you just hit the jackpot."

Someone on another site suggested the speech below, but they didn't say where it came from.  Does anyone know the issue where this speech happens?

> *"You're not going to kill me Kaine... you won't even hurt me. You can't. Not if all you've told me is true. If you are a clone of Peter Parker's... then deep down, you're as good as he is. Being a clone doesn't make you... or my husband... any less of a man. You're alive! Where and how you were born into this world just doesn't matter. Peter...my Peter... has always done the right thing... has defined himself by his actions.. not by whether he was born or cloned. He has lived a valuable life for the past five years I've known him. And now I'm carrying his child... I'm not going to let him throw away the life we've shared together. Peter is a person... and so are you! Prove yourself, Kaine! By your actions! Don't let Ben be killed! Don't let the Jackal kill anymore! Do what Peter would do! So the right thing. You have the Power... now accept the responsibility"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This monologue comes from [Spider-Man V1 #61](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_Vol_1_61) (originally titled 'Peter Parker - Spider Man : A Thousand Clones).

As you can see from the panel below, MJ is speaking with one of Spider-man's clones, a man known as [Kaine](http://marvel.wikia.com/Peter_Parker_%28Kaine%29_%28Earth-616%29)...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is from [Spider-Man #61](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_Vol_1_61), published in August, 1995.

It occurs during the *Maximum Clonage* storyline.

[image: cover]

Comment: haha "Maximum Clonage" awesome